# Model won't save changes when using Model.update_attributes! during Rails 3 migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

I have the following Rails 3 migration which adds a column game_type to a table called games. It's supposed to update the value of the game_type depending on whether live is true, but this value never gets saved.

```
class AddGameTypeToGames < ActiveRecord::Migration

  class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def up
    say "Adding game_type column to Games table"
    add_column :games, :game_type, :string, :null => false, :default => 'Demo'

    say_with_time "Migrating live value into game_type column" do
      rows_affected = 0
      Game.all.each do |game|
        if game.live
          game.update_attributes!(:game_type => 'Live')
          rows_affected += 1
        end
      end
      rows_affected
    end
  end
end
```

I eventually got this to work by changing the line `game.update_attributes!(:game_type => 'Live')` to `Game.connection.execute("UPDATE games SET game_type='Live' where id = #{game.id}")`.

I'm wondering why update_attributes! wouldn't work? I have other migrations where this works fine. Including the model is supposed to stop validations getting in the way of the migration. I tried setting `attr_accessible :game_type` on the Game model in the migration, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to add this line before running the loop on Game model

```
Game.reset_column_information
Game.all.each do |game|
  ....
  ....
```

Sometimes you’ll want to add a column in a migration and populate it immediately after. In that case, you’ll need to make a call to Base#reset_column_information in order to ensure that the model has the latest column data from after the new column was added.

There's an example of this in the API docs for [ActiveRecord::Migration](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html). Look for "Using a model after changing its table"